# vagrant host name with port number does not execute php file

Tags: php, apache, symfony, ubuntu, vagrant

I am using vagrant tool for virtulization, below are the version number of OS and tools I am using.

Ubuntu : 13.04

Vagrant : Vagrant 1.5.1

VM box : 4.2.10_Ubuntur84101

Below is my vagrant file content

```
    # -*- mode: ruby -*-
    # vi: set ft=ruby :

    # Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
    VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

    Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
      # All Vagrant configuration is done here. The most common configuration
      # options are documented and commented below. For a complete reference,
      # please see the online documentation at vagrantup.com.

      # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
      config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise32"
      config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "getmyltd_bootstrap.sh"
      config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 4567, guest: 80

      # The url from where the 'config.vm.box' box will be fetched if it
      # doesn't already exist on the user's system.
      # config.vm.box_url = "http://domain.com/path/to/above.box"

      # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
      # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
      # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
      # config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080

      # Create a private network, which allows host-only access to the machine
      # using a specific IP.
      # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"

      # Create a public network, which generally matched to bridged network.
      # Bridged networks make the machine appear as another physical device on
      # your network.
      # config.vm.network "public_network"

      # If true, then any SSH connections made will enable agent forwarding.
      # Default value: false
      # config.ssh.forward_agent = true

      # Share an additional folder to the guest VM. The first argument is
      # the path on the host to the actual folder. The second argument is
      # the path on the guest to mount the folder. And the optional third
      # argument is a set of non-required options.
      # config.vm.synced_folder "../data", "/vagrant_data"

      # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
      # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
      # Example for VirtualBox:
      #
      # config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      #   # Don't boot with headless mode
      #   vb.gui = true
      #
      #   # Use VBoxManage to customize the VM. For example to change memory:
      #   vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
      # end
      #
      # View the documentation for the provider you're using for more
      # information on available options.

      # Enable provisioning with Puppet stand alone.  Puppet manifests
      # are contained in a directory path relative to this Vagrantfile.
      # You will need to create the manifests directory and a manifest in
      # the file hashicorp/precise32.pp in the manifests_path directory.
      #
      # An example Puppet manifest to provision the message of the day:
      #
      # # group { "puppet":
      # #   ensure => "present",
      # # }
      # #
      # # File { owner => 0, group => 0, mode => 0644 }
      # #
      # # file { '/etc/motd':
      # #   content => "Welcome to your Vagrant-built virtual machine!
      # #               Managed by Puppet.\n"
      # # }
      #
      # config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
      #   puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
      #   puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
      # end

      # Enable provisioning with chef solo, specifying a cookbooks path, roles
      # path, and data_bags path (all relative to this Vagrantfile), and adding
      # some recipes and/or roles.
      #
      # config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
      #   chef.cookbooks_path = "../my-recipes/cookbooks"
      #   chef.roles_path = "../my-recipes/roles"
      #   chef.data_bags_path = "../my-recipes/data_bags"
      #   chef.add_recipe "mysql"
      #   chef.add_role "web"
      #
      #   # You may also specify custom JSON attributes:
      #   chef.json = { :mysql_password => "foo" }
      # end

      # Enable provisioning with chef server, specifying the chef server URL,
      # and the path to the validation key (relative to this Vagrantfile).
      #
      # The Opscode Platform uses HTTPS. Substitute your organization for
      # ORGNAME in the URL and validation key.
      #
      # If you have your own Chef Server, use the appropriate URL, which may be
      # HTTP instead of HTTPS depending on your configuration. Also change the
      # validation key to validation.pem.
      #
      # config.vm.provision "chef_client" do |chef|
      #   chef.chef_server_url = "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/ORGNAME"
      #   chef.validation_key_path = "ORGNAME-validator.pem"
      # end
      #
      # If you're using the Opscode platform, your validator client is
      # ORGNAME-validator, replacing ORGNAME with your organization name.
      #
      # If you have your own Chef Server, the default validation client name is
      # chef-validator, unless you changed the configuration.
      #
      #   chef.validation_client_name = "ORGNAME-validator"
    end
```

Vagrant up, vagrant reload commands works fine without any errors. and enables the port number 4567 successfully.

In my local machine I have a virtual host, content of that is as below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName *.testmyltd.com
        ServerAlias admin.testmyltd.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/getmyltd/web
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

    <VirtualHost *:4567>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            ServerName *.testmyltd.com
            ServerAlias admin.testmyltd.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/getmyltd/web
            <Directory />
                    Options FollowSymLinks
                    AllowOverride None
            </Directory>
            <Directory /var/www/>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride None
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
            </Directory>

            ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
            <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                    AllowOverride None
                    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

            # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
            # alert, emerg.
            LogLevel warn

            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

When my VM is working state `http://admin.testmyltd.com:4567` and `http://admin.testmyltd.com` gives me access to my project directory, it's image is as below

[image]

Hitting `http://admin.testmyltd.com/app_dev.php` runs default route properly, but hitting `http://admin.testmyltd.com:4567/app_dev.php` downloads app_dev.php file instead of executing it.

All file in project have full permissions.

getmyltd_bootstrap.sh file content is here

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# steps followed from http://www.walmik.com/2013/04/install-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/

touch track_bootstrap_file.txt
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
echo -e  "\n\n\t\t------   project configuration  -------\n\n"


echo  -e  "\n\n\t\tStep 1 of 5 ===> Updating existing packages <===\n\n"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 456123'
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 456123'
#echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password 456123' | debconf-set-selections
#echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password 456123' | debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get update 
echo "step 1 of 5 - packages updated" > track_bootstrap_file.txt


echo  -e  "\n\n\t\tStep 2 of 5 ===> Installing mysql server <===\n\n"
sudo apt-get -y install mysql-server-5.5 php5-mysql 
echo "step 2 of 5 - mysql server installed" >> track_bootstrap_file.txt


echo  -e  "\n\n\t\tStep 3 of 5 ===> Installing Apache server <===\n\n"
sudo apt-get install -y apache2
echo "step 3 of 5 - apache server installed" >> track_bootstrap_file.txt


echo  -e  "\n\n\t\tStep 4 of 5 ===> Installing php5 <===\n\n"

sudo apt-get install  -y  php5 mysql-server mongodb-server php5-mysql apache2 git-core vim php5-cli php5-json curl php5-intl #php5-mongo
sudo service apache2 restart 
echo "step 4 of 5 - php5 installed" >> track_bootstrap_file.txt


echo  -e  "\n\n\t\tStep 5 of 5 ===> Restarting apache2 <===\n\n"
sudo service apache2 restart 
echo "step 5 of 5 - Restarted apache2 server successfully" >> track_bootstrap_file.txt


echo  -e  "\n\n\n\t\t-----  Wohoo... Your machine configuration is ready now.   -------\n\n"
echo "All operations from getmyltd_bootstrap.sh executed successfully" >> track_bootstrap_file.txt
```

Can you guide me where the things went wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like either Apache or PHP isn't configured correctly. Can provide the contents of getmyltd_bootstrap.sh so we can see how the VM is being provisioned?

Comment: @Kunal , I have added file's content.. Please have a look.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install `libapache2-mod-php5` in guest os (vagrant box) to execute `.php` scripts,

```
$sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```

Then if required, enable it manually,

```
$sudo a2enmod php5
```

and finally restart your apache2

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

**EDIT**

Make sure your apache under vagrant box is Listening on port "4567" as you want it to access from that specific port.

**/etc/apache2/httpd.conf**

```
Listen 4567
```

Comment: Yes I have installed, that was missuing... but still i couldn't reach the solution.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try running

```
vagrant provision
```

I'm not convinced your `getmyltd_bootstrap.sh` file is running.

Comment: Interesting. I always seem to have to run provision separately in order to achieve anything, but maybe I need to upgrade or something.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned version numbers of tools I am using currently, you please take a look on that, if you need more information about my pc's current installation, I will provide.. Thanks Jez